# FIRUserProfileChangeRequest where data are stored

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Where this data are stored ?

changeRequest.photoURL

Because :

1. Simulator one (5 inch): changeRequest.photoURL = http://xxx...../1.jpg
2. I use now simulator Two (4.7 inch) witch the same user and change photoUrl :
   changeRequest.photoURL = http://xxx...../2.jpg

If i go now in simulator one when i asked for user.photoUrl it's always 1.jpg.... (so error) and not 2.jpg

So this data are stored in phone and not in firebase... can someone confirm this pls ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The value that you provide for [`FIRUserProfileChangeRequest.photoURL`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_user_profile_change_request), must point to a publicly accessible image for the user.

For comparison: this is your public profile image's URL for Stack Overflow: `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ebee97695ce4f9bc246d73714972745?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1`, which shows as [image: pic].

The Firebase Authentication API does not automatically upload a local image you provide. If you're looking for a place to upload and store the local image, I recommend that you check out [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start) - specifically its section on [uploading files from iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file).